# how to pass multiple value from list box to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a table-valued parameter like this

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ss AS TABLE(ss1 integer);
```

My stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary] 
 @locations dbo.ss readonly
as
begin
...............
.............
AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (select ss1 from @locations))
```

i have a list box ..that containing multiple items..same time i can select multiple item from my listbox..that time how i can pass multiple Locationid to my stored procdure if i always select one Location from my listbox..then i can pass like this:

```
dim locid as integer=Lstbox.selectedItem
cmd.parameters.add("@locations",locid)..
```

but i dont know how to pass selected items together from listbox to stored procdure

I am working on vb.net windows forms

Answer (score 0):

Specify a type name for the table-valued parameter by using the TypeName property of  SqlParameter. The TypeName must match the name of a compatible type previously created on the server as:

```
tvp1.TypeName = "dbo.ss"
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: it's not 'DbType' property of SqlParameter. It's 'TypeName'. This link will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: i given like this:but now i am getting error:Operand type clash: table type is incompatible with int

Comment: sir now i given what u said:tvp1.TypeName = "dbo.ss" but error coming :Operand type clash: table type is incompatible with int

Comment: i cheked that link,,now my code s almost same..but still am getting error

Comment: As i can see you are not returning any thing from stored procedure but in code you have written SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand along with Fill to select records from the database for placement in the DataSet. Replace these last two lines with cmd23.ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: i want to take this data to data set..thats why i am doing like this.if i do cmd23.ExecuteNonQuery() how i can take data to data set